# Case statement with end = 1 in T/SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm hoping somebody can explain the below query to me as I'm not familiar with the syntax:

```
@[user1]   int,
@[user2]   varchar(10)

delete 
from [table name]
where [id] in (select [id]
            from [a diff table name]
            where [user1] = @[user1])
and (case
     when [user2] = 'some string' then 1
     when [table field] = @user2 then 1
     else 0
     end) = 1
and [other field] = 0
and [other field] = 0
and [other field]= 0
```

Firstly, I've obviously changed all variable/table names. Apologies if anything isn't clear. I get that the first part is a delete statement where it uses an in statement. That's fine. I also get the last part, with the multiple AND statements adding conditions to the WHERE clause.

It's the case statement I'm struggling with. I've two questions.

1. What is the else 0 for? Is that attached to the when clause above it, so that if [table field] doesn't = the user2 variable passed in it is set to 0?
2. What is the end = 1? I've tried googling but haven't found any examples of this form before.

Comment: I added brackets that will help explain the case statement a bit better :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ELSE 0 means that the CASE statement will return 0 if neither of the WHEN statements are matched.

End = 1 is easier to understand if you think of it as

```
WHERE (CASE .... END) = 1
```

Comment: AH, I get it. So ideally, if the case statements match, it will be "where 1 = 1", otherwise it will be "where 0 = 1" which will fail. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why a CASE expression is used here as this could be written as `AND ([user2] = 'some string' OR [table field] = @user2)`.  IMHO. this construct makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your CASE stmt will return either 1 or 0 depends on data in that column.

IF it return 1 then 1=1 and other conditions which specified below will also happen.
IF it return 0 then 0=1 , Remaining conditions won't be considered.